# Как задать координаты кнопки WPF? (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Мне нужно создать кнопку, делаю так:

`<Button x:Name="but1" Width="20" Height="20" Content="Кнопка" Background="Blue" />`

А как мне задать координаты кнопки по X и Y? Может, потом задать их уже в C# файле?

Comment: Координаты где?

Comment: Контролы можно размещать в произвольном месте только на панели Canvas, другие панели компонуют содержимое по конкретным правилам

Comment: а лучше сделать Layout для окна/страницы (например, тот же Grid).

Answer (score 1):

Использовать объек компоновки типа Canvas

```
<Canvas Background="Lavender">
            <Button Background="AliceBlue" Content="Top 20 Left 40" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="40" />
<Button Background="Aquamarine" Content="Bottom 30 Left 20" Canvas.Bottom="30" Canvas.Left="20"/>
</Canvas>
```

Так же использовать свойство ZIndex - очередь отрисовки (см. литературу)